# What's the opinion/is there a policy on signoffs on questions

Tags: discussion

I don't know a better way to ask this question other than being blunt: Is this just a pet peeve of mine, or is it generally frowned upon to add signoffs to questions? Mainly, it's just redundant.

For example, I don't like it when people end off their question with

Thanks!

~jordoex

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this question and remove the last couple lines...

Comment: That's my point. :P

Comment: Also see [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) about this.

Comment: Ok. I searched for signoff and didn't think to search for synonyms. I'm fine that this is a duplicate.